# Related to Sharepoint Technology

Tags: sharepoint

I have 3 yrs of exp. in .net and now i don't have interest in .net and i want to do a sharepoint course. I just want to know that will it be beneficial for me in the future as i m into the .net. Thanks to provide me a good suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Can you tell us specific reasons why you are bored of .NET ! In my honest opinion, if you can bored of fantastic thing like .NET in 3 years then Sharepoint will make you bore in just 3 months

Comment: I have total 3 yrs of exp. in .net but actually real time, i would hv been worked in .net for the last 1.5 yrs and i want to do the sharepoint to get the good job

Comment: Well I would say Sharepoint is lesser programming and greater tweaking compared to .NET. Moreover Sharepoint would restrict your creativity scope to its boundaries. Your thinking is correct with respect to job, that currently opportunities in Sharepoint are growing but I really doubt how qualitative / satisfying that would be.
If you really like coding, I would suggest you to stick to .NET and participate in some open source projects (www.codeplex.com) to satisfy your coding cravings :) plus look for some different job. If you dont like coding that much then you may tryout Sharepoint career.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to point out is that SharePoint is built on top of ASP.Net, so on the plus side you get to leverage some of your skills and on the negative side, if you're bored with .Net then this will be basically more of the same.

Whether or not it will be beneficial to you depends on a lot of circumstances but SharePoint is Microsoft's biggest growing product and made them over a billion dollars in the last financial year. I remember reading that for every dollar spent on SharePoint licenses, seven dollars was spent on consulting and services outside Microsoft so that's a large and vibrant ecosystem with a lot of opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like .Net, you will *hate* SharePoint.